# OpenUri and OpenSSL unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ruby, ssl, homebrew, open-uri

I'm using OpenUri to read a JSON file from a HTTPS server. It was working fine a couple of days ago but this morning I got:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
The server presented a certificate that could not be verified:
error code 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I think the server just renewed its SSL certificate so I'm wondering if that's related? Otherwise has my system lost its root certs?

I'm running Mac OS 10.11.2, Ruby 2.3.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.2e, installed with Homebrew and I use RVM.

Comment: If the server changed than it is either that you don't have the required new root CA or that the server failed to serve the full certificate chain. It might also be that you have a new OpenSSL but that ruby is linked against the old one from Mac (i.e. 0.9.8). Too few details to help you here more, but if the server is public you might add the URL to your question so that one can have a look.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich I already had to rebuild ruby to link against the new OpenSLL. The server is kimonolabs.com if you'd like to look into it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The server is kimonolabs.com

The server does not sent the intermediate certificates which are needed to built the trust chain. Thus validation fails. Browsers in these cases often use cached intermediate certificates from earlier connection to other sites or try to download the missing certificates from the web. But other clients don't do this and thus the validation fails.

See also [the report from SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=kimonolabs.com&s=54.174.7.41&latest):

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

Thus, the problem needs to be fixed at the server side.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that would break it. Hopefully they'll get that sorted soon.